# error.localizedDescription always returns English

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

In Swift/XCode I always get the English error messages as an output and not the translated local message of my device (Simulator or real device doesn't matter).
I added the localization countries in the info tap of my project, but do I have to do something else, like translating an English error file manually to e.g. German?

I know there are similar old questions on SO, and their answers all sound very simple but don't work.

Example code:

**ContentView.swift**

```
@State var errorText: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
       ...
       logIn()
       Text(errorText)
    }
}
```

.....

```
    func logIn() {

        session.logIn(email: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            if let error = error
                {
                self.errorText = error.localizedDescription
                    self.shouldAnimate = false

                return
                }
        ....
```

[image: XCode Info-Frame]

**Edit:**

I wasn't sure what I should enter here when adding German as a language. I use SwiftUI and not Storyboard if this fact matters:

[image: Adding a language]

What does work for example is the translation of the Edit Button in the Status Bar. But the error messages at the same time are always English.

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
```

Comment: What's the value of `Locale.current`?

Comment: Locale.current.description gives me: de_DE (current)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to build an extension for AuthErrorCode.
I came on this because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916157/12637422

The Localizable.strings only worked on Text("...") for me.

A solution for 2 languages could look like this (Polish and German example):

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

extension AuthErrorCode {
    var description: String? {
        switch self {
        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Adres e-mail jest już w użyciu." } else {
                return "Die E-Mailadresse wird bereits verwendet."
            }
        case .userDisabled:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Użytkownik jest obecnie dezaktywowany. Skontaktuj się z poliapp@polipol.de." } else {
                return "Der Benutzer ist zur Zeit deaktiviert. Bitte an poliapp@polipol.de wenden."
            }
        case .operationNotAllowed:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Operacja niezatwierdzona." } else {
                return "Operation nicht genehmigt."
            }
        case .invalidEmail:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Format adresu e-mail jest nieprawidłowy." } else {
                return "Das Format der E-Mailadresse ist ungültig."
            }
        case .wrongPassword:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Hasło jest nieprawidłowe." } else {
                return "Das Passwort ist nicht korrekt."
            }
        case .userNotFound:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Nie znaleziono odpowiedniego konta użytkownika." } else {
                return "Kein entsprechendes Benutzerkonto gefunden."
            }
        case .networkError:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Wystąpił błąd sieci. Proszę spróbuj ponownie." } else {
                return "Es ist ein Netzwerkfehler aufgetreten. Bitte erneut versuchen."
            }
        case .weakPassword:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Hasło jest za słabe." } else {
                return "Das Passwort ist zu schwach."
            }
        case .missingEmail:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Proszę podać adres e-mail." } else {
                return "Bitte eine E-Mailadresse angeben."
            }
        case .internalError:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Błąd wewnętrzny Proszę spróbuj ponownie." } else {
                return "Interner Fehler. Bitte erneut versuchen."
            }
        case .invalidCustomToken:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Token jest nieprawidłowy." } else {
                return "Das Token ist ungültig."
            }
        case .tooManyRequests:
            if Locale.current.languageCode == "pl" {
                return "Wysłałeś zbyt wiele żądań do serwera. Proszę chwilę poczekać." } else {
                return "Sie haben zu viele Anfragen an den Server gesendet. Bitte etwas warten."
            }
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

public extension Error {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        let error = self as NSError
        if error.domain == AuthErrorDomain {
            if let code = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
                if let errorString = code.description {
                    return errorString
                }
            }
        }
        return error.localizedDescription
    } }
```